# QGIS 2.4 Heatmap Plugin Generates a Solid Black Map

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, heat-map

I'm trying to generate a heatmap of vehicle-pedestrian collisions in Los Angeles using data taken from UC Berekely TIMS. TIMS provides an exhaustive database of traffic accidents involving injury in the state of California.

I have a subset of the data mapped out in QGIS, and I'm attempting to create a heatmap using the heatmap plugin. However, instead of getting a heatmap, I get a solid black heatmap file. Moreover, when I try to open the properties screen, QGIS simply alerts me, "Bad Allocation," and won't refuses to open the property screen. I am using the default settings, with a radius of 200m (though I also tried 50m).

[image: Screenshot of settings]

I tried to do this in QGIS 2.0, but I still get the black box. Am I missing some critical information on how to use the heatmap plugin?

Comment: What's your data CRS and your project CRS? If your data is in WGS84, try reprojecting it. You could also include a screenshot of the QGIS window and the plugin settings you used.

Comment: Both are WGS84 right now. What projection would you recommend? I'll get a screenshot in.

Comment: I *think* this is a bug in the Windows build of QGIS. I'll do some more testing and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bunch of bugs in the heatmap code which I've now fixed. You can either download an updated development snapshot to get these fixes, or for QGIS < 2.6 there's some workarounds:

- make sure your layer isn't a "multipoint" layer
- there's a bug which causes the layer choice from the dialog not to apply the first time in a session. Rerunning the heatmap a second time should work around this.

Comment: That makes sense then -- I'm importing the data from Spatalite due to the sheer size of the database. I'll download a development snapshot and report back with the results.

Comment: Sure enough -- Singlepart geometry (Used VEctor -> Geomtery Tools -> Multipart to Singleparts)  is a usable workaround in QGIS 2.4!